# Get child and grandchild id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#save").click(function() {

    $("#div1").css({
      position: 'relative'
    });

    var a = $('#div1').children();
    a.each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr('id') == 'TextBoxesGroup') {
        var b = $(this).children().children();
        b.each(function() {
          continues($(this).attr('id'));
        });
      } else {
        continues($(this).attr('id'));
      }

    });

  });

});

var label = "";

function continues(id) {
  if (id != "") {
    //get label text
    if (id.substr(0, 5) == "label")

      label = $("#" + id).text();
    //alert("Get label id"+label+'181');

    var eid = id;
    //console.log("id"+eid);
    savePosition(eid, label);
  }
}

function savePosition(eid, label) { //console.log("#id"+"#" + eid);
  $("#" + eid).css({
    position: 'absolute'
  });
  var x = $("#" + eid).position();
  alert("name: " + eid + "Top position: " + x.top + " Left position: " + x.left + "label:" + label);

  continues();

}
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 610px;
  height: 330px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class="relative" style="position:relative">

  <div id="TextBoxesGroup">
    <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
      <label id="label1">Text Here</label>
      <input id="textbox1" class="clickedit" type="text" class="draggable" placeholder="Text Here" />
      <div class="clearfix" id="hey"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<button id="save">Save</button>
```

My jQuery need to get all of the element ID to save in with its position. However, I keep getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

What should i do? 
** I had modify the question a bit because some part are link to other parts which are difficult to add in

Comment: Why not use `x`(`x.top`) instead?

Comment: @Rajesh oh ya but the error still occur..

Comment: Have you made sure that `$("#" + eid)` is actually defined?

Comment: Try logging `eid`, `$("#"+eid)` and `x`. This should make it easier for you to understand where issue exists.

Comment: Nothing came out.. @Rajesh but as always some data are save in my save.php. And everytime the data save differently --> eg. First time save info of the label and textbox. Second time save info of qr and label

Comment: I can't see `#save` button in your code. Please create a snippet or bin or fiddle with this problem so we could help you.

Comment: @MoshFeu nothing wrong with the button and i dont know how to create a snippet or bin or fiddle ...

Comment: [Add a nippet to your question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or use [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/?html,css,js,output) to show us the problem. Just add the relevant code there and share the URL with us.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because `data` is wrong.

Please try replace your `savePosition` function by this below:

```
function savePosition(eid,label)
{
    $("#" + eid).css({position:'absolute'});
    var x = $("#" + eid).position();
    xTop = x.top;
    xLeft = x.left;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../../save.php",
        data: { name: eid,
                top: xTop,
                left: xLeft,
                txt: label
                },

        success:function(data) 
        {
                continues();
        }
    });
}
```